# unexpected behavior when including a personal three.js library

Tags: three.js, aframe

Caveat: The following was empirically determined.

If you are writing an app in Aframe, just be aware that you do not need to include a three.js lib in your html since AFrame ships with it's own version of three.js and the non-Aframe portions of your app can use this version of three.js as well.  As a matter of fact, not only do you not need it, you should definitely *not* include it.

If you include your own version of three.js then AFrame will use that over the one it was built with.  While most of the time this won't cause problems, it can lead to unpredictable results.  For Instance, I was mixing Aframe-master.js v0.5, which assumes three.js v84 and also src'ing in three.js v85 and I received the following error messages:

```
Uncaught Error: `Entity.setObject3D` was called with an object that was not an instance of THREE.Object3D.
    at HTMLElement.value (aframe-master.js:72729)
    at aframe-master.js:66470
    at aframe-master.js:48132
    at ObjectLoader.parse (Three.js:32979)
    at Three.js:32938
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (Three.js:29098)
```

After much research, I determined this is because in three.js v85 they [dropped the blendCharacter object](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/2616) but aframe-master v0.5 is built against three.js v84 which still does have it and assumes it's there.

I was running mixed versions fine for a while, so it's a subtle error.  If you do get a situation, you will most definitely get some other error.  I'm just documenting this because I spent half a day trying to figure this out and maybe I can spare someone else the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

If using AFrame, do not include three.js in your html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>A-frame controller test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
  <script src="lib/aframe-master.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js" integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="lib/Three.js"></script> <!-- remove this -->
  <script src="lib/grab.js"></script> 
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <a-scene>
```

Look on the console and make sure Aframe and three.WebGlRenderer are using the same version:

Bad (mixed three.js 0.84 and 0.85):

```
A-Frame Version: 0.5.0 (Date 03-05-2017, Commit #31d05b0)
aframe-master.js:76936 three Version: ^0.84.0
aframe-master.js:76937 WebVR Polyfill Version: dmarcos/webvr-polyfill#a02a8089b
THREE.WebGLRenderer 85dev
```

Good (three.js v.84 everywhere):

```
A-Frame Version: 0.5.0 (Date 03-05-2017, Commit #31d05b0)
aframe-master.js:76936three Version: ^0.84.0
aframe-master.js:76937WebVR Polyfill Version: dmarcos/webvr-polyfill#a02a8089b
aframe-master.js:24581 THREE.WebGLRenderer 84
```